# adb shell dropping escaped double quote?

Tags: android, shell, cmd, adb

[image: demonstration of the problem]

Hi guys.  I'm trying to write a file to an android device that requires quotes in its body.  I would like to avoid using "adb push" since that requires me to save a temporary file and delete it afterwards.  I am using adb shell echo and piping it to a .txt file.  The issue is that even when I escape the double quotes with a backslash the file is not saving the quotes at all.  I am able get the quotes to appear while I am in the adb shell terminal while executing the exact same command.

Any help would be much appreciated I'm really at a loss here.  Thanks.

Comment: Please add formatted text instead of images

Comment: You're quoting within quotes in that command.  That means you need to do \\\"  escaping both the backslash and the quote in order to make it go through correctly.

Comment: Gabe Sechan's solution worked splendidly thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use single quote, for instance:

```
adb shell 'echo \"hello world\" > /sdcard/hello.txt'

adb shell cat /sdcard/hello.txt

"hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the hex code 0x22 for double quotes

```
adb shell "echo '\x22hello world\x22' > /sdcard/hello.txt"
adb shell cat /sdcard/hello.txt
"hello world"
```